# Need to understand the file transfer mode

Tags: java, ssh, bit-manipulation, sftp

I am doing the file transfer using `SFTP API` (`jsacpe`).

The files are basically a text content with the extension `.log, .dat`,`.txt` or `.jrn`. Before transferring the file i am doing the `AES encryption`.

The file transfer mode is 'Automatic'.

sample code:

```
    SshParameters sshParameters = new SshParameters("127.0.0.1",22,"User Name","Password");
    SshHostKeys sshHostKeys = new SshHostKeys();
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1);
    sshHostKeys.addKey(address, "finger print");
    HostKeyVerifier keyVerifier = new HostKeyFingerprintVerifier(sshHostKeys);
    sshParameters.setHostKeyVerifier(keyVerifier);

    sftp = new Sftp(sshParameters);
    sftp.setTimeout(30 * 1000);
    sftp.setDownloadBlockSize(300);
    sftp.setUploadBlockSize(300);
    sftp.setSendBufferSize(300);
    sftp.setReceiveBufferSize(300);
    sftp.addSftpListener(this);
    sftp.connect();

    **sftp.setAuto(true);**
```

I want to know in which mode(ASCII or Binary) the sftp will transfer the file.

How the sftp api will decide the ftp mode if we set it as 'automatic' because the extension type will differ for each set of files.

```
May be this is an basic question but i want to understand.
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: as the data will always be encrypted to binary ....

Comment: If you're encrypting the files, use BINARY. In fact, there's really no need to use anything else unless you're using some odd character encoding that FTP handles for you. However, since you're using SFTP, why are you encrypting the files?

Answer (score 0):

SFTP protocol by default uses binary mode and until SFTP version 4 it didn't even have ASCII mode. Some software (including our SecureBlackbox library) can emulate ASCII mode but such emulation is not very reliable as it's not known what EOL convention the target system uses.

Now as said in comments you better stick with Binary mode and don't rely on anything automatic. I can imagine that on certain small files automatic detection can fail miserably, thus spoiling your data.

Comment: Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Thanks for your reply, i'll try with default binary setting

Comment: @User1234  proper way to thank on StackOverflow network is to upvote the answer. If your question in whole is answered in some particular answer, you need to mark that answer as accepted to let others know that the question has been answered. The checkmark is located under the vote buttons.